# How to map 'kk' to Ctrl+O (Vim)

Tags: vim

I want to map <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> so I can more easily escape insert mode to issue some key commands (I rather dislike using the backspace and delete keys).

I can issue the following command in a vim session to achieve the desired result

```
:imap kk <C-O>
```

But if I put this line in my `.vimrc` file, pressing <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> does nothing (even the 'kk' doesn't get printed).

```
imap kk <C-O>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @j_mcnally vim questions are on topic at SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: `:imap kk <C-O>` works fine for me (mvim 7.3(53) on OS X 10.5.8). What version of vim, and what OS are you using?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I think this was a colossal blunder on my part. I had a space at the end of `<C-O>`

Comment: So instead of using <del> and <bs> now you have to use <C-O> and then x or ...? How is that easier in any way, I wonder? ... Anyways ...

Comment: @ldigas it isn't, but it's a work in progress. Something like `jf` is easier, but you can't hold j down like so `jfffffffff`. Maybe `<C-,>`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @puk - Most people who are unsatisfied with <esc> ("it being too far away") use jj.

Comment: @ldigas yes I too have `jj` mapped to `<esc>` but wanted something more central than `<BS>` as I use it quite often, maybe `<C-H>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had a space at the end of my line so `kk` was being remapped to `<C-O>' '` and the space command doesn't do anything. Let this be a warning to all: Trailing spaces are evil.

---

I can't believe no one has pointed this out. There are a whole host of `vi` (not `vim`) key mappings for insert mode I never knew about (I can't guarantee they all work in `vim`). For example

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> --> Backspace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> --> Return/Enter

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> --> Tab

Here is the [full list](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html)

Comment: Have a look at [this article on highlighting trailing whitespace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces)